# How to pipe password to sudo with zenity, pv and dd

Tags: bash, sudo, dd, zenity, pv

I want to let users write an ISO to a USB pen drive from within Thunar or Dolphin.

For this I've created a bash script which uses dd, pv and zenity.

Currently I'm using pkexec to ask for a password before the dd command is executed, but the pkexec window and the zenity progress window are both opened at the same time. I'd like to open a window for the root password first after which the zenity progress window should be opened.

I tried to ask for the password with zenity first after which I pipe the password to sudo but wherever I put the "echo $PWD", the password is not piped into sudo.

```
#!/bin/bash

TITLE='Zenity Progress Test'

PASSWORD=$(zenity --password \
                     --width=300 \
                     --title="$TITLE")
if [ ! -z "$PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "Your password: $PASSWORD"
    dd if=/dev/zero of="$PWD/testfile1" bs=1M count=100
    pv -n testfile1 2> >(zenity --progress \
                                           --width=300 \
                                           --title="$TITLE" \
                                           --percentage=0 \
                                           --auto-close \
                                           --auto-kill) | echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S dd of="$PWD/testfile2" bs=64k oflag=dsync
    echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S rm "$PWD/testfile1" "$PWD/testfile2"
else
    echo 'No password provided'
    exit 1
fi
```

The zenity progress window just flashes by and nothing is transferred, most likely because the password is not piped into sudo.

If you replace "echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S" with "pkexec" the code functions but with both the pkexec window and the zenity progress window opened together.

Any ideas on how to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

Use param -S for read from stdin

```
$echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Comment: That's what I did as described in the OP: "echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S dd"